# Parsing a string : my code apparentely works after testing, but is inelegant

Tags: c++, string, parsing, char

This is a `c++` question. I want the code of the desired `c++` function (see below) to be (as much as possible) in `c`-style and using `c` string library functions because I think that this will lead the quickest code in terms of execution time. (Am I wrong ? If so, how much ?) Yes, I value performance more than readability for this question because the desired function will be called **a lot** (millions) of times.

I am receiving `const char *`'s of the form "25Dec2016" that represent dates and I am parsing them to back out from them three `int`'s (one for the day, the second for the month and the last for the year (that I assumed to be a number between 0 and 9999)) thanks to a function

```
Parse(const char * cDate, int & day, int & month, int & year)
```

I coded such a function and tested it : it works on correct `const char*`s (those that indeed represent date in my format), but I feel that my use of `c` functions (`atoi` for instance) is incorrect, even if I don't see why. There are also other problems :

- the code is inelegant (the big `if ... else if ... if`) : one cannot do a `switch` statement on a string, but is there an elegant way to do this without resorting the `std::map` and `c++11` ?
- surely problematic from a c string point of view (I am not an expert) : for instance, I am really not happy with the way I extract the three substring into "buffers" ... Plus it appears I have problems with not null terminated `char` arrays that I'd like to correct. I could force a `\0` at the end of `_day` and `_year` as I did for `_month` but I find that doing so is awful, so that I suspect a bad "design" of my parsing function
- quite bad from an error handling point of view : the function is not a constructor for now, but could finally be, this is the reason why I `throw`.

I am open to any comments !

Here is the initial code :

```
Parse(const char * cDate, int & day, int & month, int & year)
{
    if (0 == cDate)
    {
        throw "Error : null string pointer";
    }
    else
    {
        if (strlen(cDate) < 8)
        {
            throw "Error : invalid string format";
        }
        else
        {
            char _day[2];
            char _month[4];
            char _year[5]; // implictely the biggest year we authorize is 99999 ; it should suffice
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
            {
                _day[i] = cDate[i];
            }
            day = atoi(_day); // if fail, Undefined behaviour, see strtol for a more robust cross-platform alternative
            char c;
            for (int i = 2; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                c = cDate[i];
                _month[i-2] = toupper(c);
            }
            _month[3] = '\0';
            if (0 == strcmp("JAN", _month))
            {
                month = 1;
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("FEB", _month))
            {
                month = 2;
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("MAR", _month))
            {
                month = 3;
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("APR",_month))
            {
                month = 4;
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("MAY", _month))
            {
                month = 5;
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("JUN", _month))
            {
                month = 6;
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("JUL", _month))
            {
                month = 7;
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("AUG", _month))
            {
                month = 8;
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("SEP", _month))
            {
                month = 9;
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("OCT",_month))
            {
                month = 10;
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("NOV", _month))
            {
                month = 11;
            }
            else if (0 == strcmp("DEC", _month))
            {
                month = 12;
            }
            else
            {
                throw "Error : invalid month string";
            }
            for (int i = 5; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                _year[i-5] = cDate[i];
            }
            year = atoi(_year);
        }
    }
}
```

I finally opted for the function to be a constructor of a `Date` class, and inspired myself from [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39059841/4455382) also using `strtol` as I intended initially (see comment in my initial code) instead of `atoi`:

```
#include <cstring> // for strlen
#include <ctype.h> // for toppuer
#include <stdlib.h>

int up(char c)
{
    return toupper((unsigned char)(c));
}

Date::Date(const char * cDate)
{
    if (0 == cDate)
    {
        throw "Error : null string pointer";
    }
    else
    {
        if (strlen(cDate) < 8)
        {
            throw "Error : invalid string format. String format is DDMMMYYYY with M's in upper or lower case"; // for now, valid format is 24Oct1979
        }
        else
        {
            char * ppEnd;
            int day = strtol(cDate, &ppEnd, 10);
            if (0 == day)
                throw "Error : invalid string format. String format is DDMMMYYYY with M's in upper or lower case";
            m_Day = day;
            char cMonth[4];
            int month;
            memcpy(cMonth, &ppEnd[0], 3);
            switch (up(cMonth[0]))
            {
                case 'A':
                {
                    switch (up(cMonth[1]))
                    {
                    case 'P': if (up(cMonth[2]) == 'R') month = 4;
                        break;
                    case 'U': if (up(cMonth[2]) == 'G') month = 8;
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 'D':
                {
                    if (up(cMonth[1]) == 'E' && up(cMonth[2]) == 'C')
                        month = 12;
                    break;
                }
                case 'F':
                {
                    if (up(cMonth[1]) == 'E' && up(cMonth[2]) == 'B')
                        month = 2;
                    break;
                }
                case 'J':
                {
                    switch (up(cMonth[1]))
                    {
                    case 'A': if (up(cMonth[2]) == 'N')
                        month = 1;
                        break;
                    case 'U': switch (up(cMonth[2]))
                    {
                    case 'N': month = 6;
                    case 'L': month = 7;
                    }
                              break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 'M':
                {
                    if (up(cMonth[1]) == 'A')
                    {
                        switch (up(cMonth[2]))
                        {
                        case 'R': month = 3;
                        case 'Y': month = 5;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 'N':
                {
                    if (up(cMonth[1]) == 'O' && up(cMonth[2]) == 'V') month = 11;
                    break;
                }
                case 'O':
                {
                    if (up(cMonth[1]) == 'C' && up(cMonth[2]) == 'T') month = 10;
                    break;
                }
                case 'S':
                {
                    if (up(cMonth[1]) == 'E' && up(cMonth[2]) == 'P') month = 9;
                    break;
                }
            }
            m_Month = (Month)month;
            int year = strtol(ppEnd + 3, &ppEnd, 10);
            if (0 == year)
                throw "Error : invalid string format. String format is DDMMMYYYY with M's in upper or lower case";
            m_Year = year;
            updateSerial();
        }
    }
}
```

*Remark.* Being lazy, I did not throw everywhere I should in the "month" part of the code.

Comment: You can use a `std::map<std::string,int>`instead.

Comment: Do you want this to be C or C++?

Comment: @beta c was out of question when seeing `throw` is used in the sample.

Comment: You have plenty of *undefined behaviors* in your code, because of unterminated C-style strings.

Comment: not part of your main question, but suggest using an exception class instead of throwing a string literal. Makes it easier for whoever is catching the exceptions. E.g. `std::runtime_error` or `std::logic_error`.  Also it is silly  to have `if(bla) { throw... } else { }`.  Take out the `else` because `throw` changes the execution point

Comment: Besides that you should probably have posted this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I edit my question, I want C style, except maybe for throwing

Comment: this is a question for codereview, not stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for CodeReview.

Comment: Code review is for code that works.  This code surely doesn't work correctly due to character arrays that are not null-terminated.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Oh, thx for the codereview.stackexchange.com mention, did not know of it. Is it possible to "move" my current question from here to there, to avoid double posting or closing ?

Comment: why doesn't the "Close > Migration" option let you choose CodeReview ><

Comment: That insistence of programming C in C++, why is that? You could probably have made the code *much* more "elegant" with some nice C++ [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), [strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: @EricFlorentNoube _"I want c-style"_ How silly is that? Why actually?

Comment: What's the problem with not null-terminated arrays ?

Comment: All C-string needs to be terminated by the `'\0'` character. That's what all the C string functions look for to know when a string ends. If there's no terminator then the string functions will go out of bounds. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*. So a string with two character needs actually *three* characters, the last one being the terminator.

Comment: @EricFlorentNoube -- `day = atoi(_day);` -- That's what's wrong with not null-terminated arrays.  The `atoi` function can fly off the handle due to `_day` not being null-terminated.

Comment: looks like the migration choice is [broken by design](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253869/can-we-have-more-options-in-the-closing-off-topic-migration)

Comment: @EricFlorentNoube _"What's the problem with not null-terminated arrays ? "_ That they aren't null terminated? You're really leaving us in confusion what your actual problems are. Improve your question please!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mean : I tested the code with `const char *`'s of the form I intended to received, and it works. Besides undefined behaviour with `atoi`, I therefore don't see what the problem is with should-be null terminated arrays that aren't. They should be because it is a rule even if it's not needed here, or because I really have also undef behaviour because of that ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh ok, thank's for the tip on `atoi` for non null terminated arrays... I could add a `\0` at the end of `_day`, as I did for `_month`, but it's really awful. (I sense I'm doing something wrong.)

Comment: I'd recommend [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) if you have access to this function and readability is preferred over performance.

Comment: @DafangCao Performance is really important to me here. Once the function will be validated, I won't change it anymore, so I can bear with "bad" readability for this one

Comment: @EricFlorentNoube -- If you want "elegant code" (and it probably isn't eventhat elegant), and since you're using C++, then [try this](http://ideone.com/kQ2lXP).

Comment: @EricFlorentNoube Please avoid tagging both C and C++ unless your question involves both languages.  They are not the same, so it would be appreciated if you could [edit] the question to remove any irrelevant tags.

Comment: In a universal/well-known context, the only arrays that need to be NULL terminated are `char` array `c` strings. In any other context, NULL termination universally means nothing. `0x00` is valid data in many, many contexts (black color in a photo for instance). Of course, if you have a specific protocol, NULL termination may be valid. 100% depends on the context.

Comment: That's definitively not C. Stop spamming tags!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thx for your proposal Paul. I did not opt for it (see reasons in the edit of my question), even if I tried the code. Had a problem (`gcc_5.4.1`) with `std::map<T,U>={{...},...,{───}}` even when passing the `-std=c++11` option

Comment: @yano Indeed... it is good to put it as you did : null termination is just a convention to avoid the obligation for `c` style string library functions to have supplementary "`int`" parameters handling string lengths. Am i wrong ?

Comment: I can't speak to the orgins of `c` strings, but that would be a good guess. Without a terminating character, `c` strings would have to be structs with `char* data` and `int length` fields, or something to that effect.

Comment: Strange thing (under Ubuntu 16.04 bits + `gcc-5.4.1`). Doing `const char * toto = "toto";` and `std::cout`'ing the first four characters, gives what's expected, `std::cout`'ing `toto[4]` gives null as expected ... but `std::cout`'ing `toto[5]` also, as many others indexes after ! (At some point one gets a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)") What is exactly behind `const char * toto = "toto";` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system is Posix-compatible, then you could just use `strptime` with the format `%d%b%Y`:

```
bool Parse(const char* date, int& day, int& month, int& year) {
    struct tm components;
    const char* rest = strptime(date, "%d%b%Y", &components);
    if (rest == NULL || *rest != '\0') return false;
    day = components.tm_mday;
    month = components.tm_mon;
    year = components.tm_year + 1900;
    return true;
}
```

That is likely to be as fast as a naive parser, and it is certainly a lot easier to write :)

Otherwise, you should use `strtol` rather than `atoi`, since it will let you know both whether the parse was successful and where the next character is. And if you want to parse the month names *quickly*, you'll want to build a trie, either as a table or directly in code (the table is probably faster, fwiw):

```
static int up(char c) { return toupper((unsigned char)(c)); }
int parseMonth(const char* p) {
  switch (up(p[0])) {
    case 'A': {
      switch (up(p[1])) {
        case 'P': if (up(p[2]) == 'R') return 4;
                  break;
        case 'U': if (up(p[2]) == 'G') return 8;
                  break;
      }
      break;
    }
    case 'D': {
      if (up(p[1]) == 'E' && up(p[2]) == 'C') return 12;
      break;
    }
    case 'F': {
      if (up(p[1]) == 'E' && up(p[2]) == 'B') return 2;
      break;
    }
    case 'J': {
      switch (up(p[1])) {
        case 'A': if (up(p[2]) == 'N') return 1;
                  break;
        case 'U': switch (up(p[2])) {
                    case 'N': return 6;
                    case 'L': return 7;
                  }
                  break;
      }
      break;
    }
    case 'M': {
      if (up(p[1]) == 'A') {
        switch (up(p[2])) {
          case 'R': return 3;
          case 'Y': return 5;
        }
      }
      break;
    }
    case 'N': {
      if (up(p[1]) == 'O' && up(p[2]) == 'V') return 11;
      break;
    }
    case 'O': {
      if (up(p[1]) == 'C' && up(p[2]) == 'T') return 10;
      break;
    }
    case 'S': {
      if (up(p[1]) == 'E' && up(p[2]) == 'P') return 9;
      break;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, if finally opted for you parsing, see my answer. What do you exactly mean by table ? (I guess that the tree approach is the one you used.)

Comment: The tree of switch statements creates a state machine. The state machine can also be written as a transition table, a two-dimensional array indexed by state and input char, whose value is the new state. In this particular case, all valid strings are three characters long, so you can traverse the tree without a conditional by just doing `state = next[state, *p++];` three times. Even without table compression techniques, the transition table would be only about 8kb.

Comment: By the way, the `memcpy` in your solution is totally unnecessary. Most compilers can optimize, fortunately; otherwise it would double the cost of parsing a month.

Comment: @eric: previous comments were for you.

Comment: Thx for the comment. I think I will try the state machine approach as well, as I am looking for the quickest code, I am open to try this ! Question : which is `memcpy(cMonth, &ppEnd[0], 3);` unnecessary ? What would you do otherwise ?

Comment: @EricFlorentNoube: I would just use the string where it is. That is, use `ppEnd` in the tests instead of `cMonth`. What do you think you gain from the use of the memcpy?

Comment: You're right. I guess that I still cannot depart from thinking that I am passing the whole array when I pass a pointer, therefore I try to minimize "lengths" of the pointers I pass... Shame on me, I know. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution based on boost Spirit X3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string.h>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

struct Month_ : x3::symbols<std::uint8_t>
{
    Month_()
    {
        add
            ("Jan", 1)
            ("Feb", 2)
            ("Mar", 3)
            ("Apr", 4)
            ("May", 5)
            ("Jun", 6)
            ("Jul", 7)
            ("Aug", 8)
            ("Sep", 9)
            ("Oct", 10)
            ("Nov", 11)
            ("Dec", 12);
    }


}month_;

using ResultType = std::tuple<int, int, int>;
namespace grammar
{
    using namespace x3;


    auto const start_ = rule<struct start_, ResultType>{"start"}
                      = int_ >> month_ >> int_;

};


int main(int athc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string str{"25Dec2016"};

    auto beg = std::begin(str);
    auto end = std::end(str);

    ResultType res;
    auto ret = x3::parse(beg,end, grammar::start_, res);
    if(ret && (beg==end) )
    {
        std::cout << "parse done :" << std::get<0>(res) << " " << std::get<1>(res) << " " << std::get<2>(res) << "\n";
    }
    else    
    {
        std::cout << "parse failed '" << std::string(beg, std::next(beg, 10)) << "'\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note, this works also with `char*`

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d259bb925a4a9839)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Here are remarks on your code and some possible simplifications:

- You can remove the `else` branches from the error handling `if` tests that `throw` an exception. As a matter of fact, you could just return a completion status instead of throwing exceptions.
- Structured exceptions would be more precise than just throwing strings, but I'm not a C++ expert.
- If the input string is null-terminated after the year part, there is no need to extract the number fields, but you might want to verify correct formatting.
- Using an array to match the month part would greatly simplify that part.

Here is a simpler version:

```
typedef enum ParseStatus {
    Parse_OK = 0,
    Parse_NullStringPointer,
    Parse_InvalidStringFormat,
    Parse_InvalidDayNumber,
    Parse_InvalidMonthName,
    Parse_InvalidYearNumber
} ParseStatus;

ParseStatus Parse(const char *cDate, int &day, int &month, int &year) {
    static const char months[4][12] = {
        "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
        "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC",
    };
    static const int maxday[12] = {
        31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
    };
    char mon[4];
    unsigned int dd, mm, yyyy;
    char c;

    if (!cDate) {
        return Parse_NullStringPointer;
    }

    /* Using sscanf for a simple solution.
     * If the string has the correct form, `sscanf` will convert 3 fields.
     * extra spaces will be accepted and ignored.
     */
    if (sscanf(cDate, "%u%3s%u%c", &dd, mon, &yyyy, &c) != 3) {
        return Parse_InvalidStringFormat;
    }

    /* If you have `strupr(char *);`, you could use it here */
    mon[0] = toupper((unsigned char)mon[0];
    mon[1] = toupper((unsigned char)mon[1];
    mon[2] = toupper((unsigned char)mon[2];

    for (mm = 0; mm < 12; mm++) {
        if (!strcmp(mon, months[mm]))
            break;
    }
    if (mm >= 12) {
        return Parse_InvalidMonthName;
    }

    /* Further validation on the day number */
    if (dd < 1 || dd > 31 || dd > maxday[mm]) {
        return Parse_InvalidDayNumber;
    }
    /* check for leap year, assuming gregorian calendar */
    if (dd == 29 && mm == 1 &&
        (yyyy % 4 != 0 || (yyyy % 100 == 0 && yyyy % 400 != 0)) {
        return Parse_InvalidDayNumber;
    }
    /* check some limits for the year */
    if (yyyy < 1 || yyyy > 9999) {
        return Parse_InvalidYearNumber;
    }

    day = dd;
    month = mm + 1;
    year = yyyy;

    return Parse_OK;
}
```

If you do not want to use `sscanf()`, you can use `strtol()` this way, but it is more cumbersome:

```
    char *p;
    int i;
    dd = strtol(cDate, &p, 10);
    for (i = 0; i < 3 && isalpha((unsigned char)p[i]); i++) {
        mon[i] = toupper((unsigned char)p[i]);
    }
    mon[i] = '\0';
    yyyy = strtol(p, &p, 10);
    if (*p != '\0') {
        return Parse_InvalidStringFormat;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to *low level* parsing I think [std::strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) is your friend because it keeps track of the current pointer position in the string you are parsing. Not that that is critical in this type of string with fixed length components. Also [std::strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) has easy error checking.

Also using iterators and algorithms helps to keep things neat and tidy.

This is about as "elegant" as I can make this using *low level* constructs:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

void parse(const char* cDate, int& day, int& month, int& year)
{
    static const char* months[] =
    {
        "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"
    };

    char* pos;
    day = std::strtol(cDate, &pos, 10);

    if(std::distance(cDate, static_cast<const char*>(pos)) != 2)
        throw std::runtime_error("bad date format");

    char mon[4] = {};
    for(auto m = std::begin(mon); m != std::end(mon) - 1; ++m)
        *m = std::toupper(*pos++);

    auto found = std::find_if(std::begin(months), std::end(months),
        [&](const char* m){ return !std::strcmp(mon, m); });

    if(found == std::end(months))
        throw std::runtime_error("bad month format");

    month = std::distance(months, found) + 1;

    char* end;
    year = std::strtol(pos, &end, 10);

    if(std::distance(pos, end) != 4)
        throw std::runtime_error("bad year format");
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        auto s = "25Dec2016";

        int d, m, y;
        parse(s, d, m, y);

        std::cout << d << "/" << m << "/" << y << '\n';
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**N.B.** Not heavily tested may contain bugs.